# Coo_matrix and other matrix examples

Tags: python, matrix

I understand this might be a very wide topic to ask but I would like to understand more about it. My question is about coo_matrix from sklearn.

I read from the documentation and understand that it represents coordinate matrix for sparse matrix. Is there any meaning to the word "coordinate" here?

For an example,

coo_matrix ((1, 2)) will get me

```
array([[0, 0]])
```

So what does the coordinate even mean in this example? Or do we have other example to differentiate it from other matrix? Such as csr_matrix, bsr_matrix or etc..

Again, If I asked the wrong question or this question could be found anywhere, please do let me know or provide me with the links, if possible.

**For the "let me know", just tell me that "You`re asking a too simple question" or "Your question could be found elsewhere, do some research" should be good and then I will delete this post as it is not relevant.

For the "share link", please do let me know where I could study and learn more about it. Thank you in advance. **

**Hint: This post according to some experts is considered to be a duplicate post and I have gained some suggestions that I can leave it here if the answer posted by other might be relevant to future readers, thus, I leave it.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy: basic clarifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216906/scipy-basic-clarifications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all you need for a coo matrix is a row list, a column list, and a value (data) list (each list being the same size). It's important that they are the same size as you will go through each element to get a triple (row index, col index, value). This tells the function to put a value at the (row index, col index) of the matrix you are making. I am pretty sure it's called the coordinate format because you pass in coordinates (with row and col) with associated values. Let's do a simple example.

```
row  = np.array([1,3])
col  = np.array([2,0])
data = np.array([5,11])
print(coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4)).toarray())
```

### Looking at the first element of each list:

`row[0] = 1` and `col[0] = 2`, thus we are going to look at the `(1,2)` element in the matrix (remember in python, indexing starts from 0). `value[0] = 5`, so the function puts 5 in as as the `(1,2)` element in the matrix.

### Looking at the second element of each list:

`row[1] = 3` and `col[1] = 0`, thus we are going to look at the `(3,0)` element in the matrix. `value[1] = 11`, so the function puts 11 in as as the `(3,0)` element in the matrix.

The rest of the elements (besides those indexed `(1,2)` and `(3,0)`) are then 0:

Output:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  5  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0]
 [11  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. This gave me a clear understanding, so the coordinate is for us to define it initially and use it to detect which coordinate it should be for the data. Btw, just a little correction, "col[0] = 2", could you edit it so that the future reader could refer to it as well.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for letting me know about my mistake, it has been corrected!

Comment: I would also suggest to add the link to the [SciPy Documentation of `coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), as well as the [SciPy lecture notes on the topic](https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/coo_matrix.html).

Comment: Nitpick: `row[0]` is at index zero but it's the *first* element.

Comment: @dennlinger Thank you for sharing the links. Since we have another answer here, can I leave this post as it is or should I just delete it since it has been marked as duplicate? I am an amateur to this site and please do guide me through. Thank you.

Comment: @JJson It seems that this is only a duplicate in my opinion, and not quite general consensus (it would otherwise be clearly highlighted). I am myself unsure about this, but would argue that - if you feel the post and answer contribute enough specific information - you could probably leave it up, with the hint that it is a potential duplicate.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will leave another hint or comment at my post to state that this might/is be a duplicate of another post.